# Depletion width of linearly doped PN-junction with unequal doping gradient

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, potential, semiconductor-physics, boundary-conditions

I am trying to find the expression for the width of the depletion layer as a function of bias voltage $V_{bi}$ for a PN-Junction with linear doping gradient but where the gradient is not the same for the P and N sides.

So for $x<0$ (P-Region) the doping concentration is:
$$N_A = -Sx$$

And for $x>0$ (N-Region) the doping concentration is:
$$N_D = Kx$$

I have found the electric field in both regions:
$$E_P=\frac {qS}{2\epsilon}(x^2 - x_p^2)$$
$$E_N=\frac {qK}{2\epsilon}(x^2 - x_n^2)$$

Where $x_p$ and $-x_n$ denote the edges of the depletion layer. I then found the expressions for potential on either side:
$$V = V_p + \frac {qM_A}{\epsilon} \left( \frac {x_p^2x}{2} - \frac {x^3}{6} + \frac {x_p^3}{3} \right)$$
$$V = V_n + \frac {qM_A}{\epsilon} \left( \frac {x_n^2x}{2} - \frac {x^3}{6} - \frac {x_p^3}{3} \right)$$

I had thought to use continuity at $x = 0$ to find an expression for $V_{bi}$ but thats where I get stuck. For the E-field we have:
$$E_p = E_P = \frac {qSx_p^2}{2\epsilon} = \frac {qKx_n^2}{2\epsilon}$$
Which gives:
$$Sx_p^2 = Kx_n^2$$

For potential:
$$V = V_p + \frac {qM_A}{\epsilon}\frac {x_p^3}{3} = V_n - \frac {qM_A}{\epsilon}\frac {x_p^3}{3}$$
$V_{bi}$ is defined as:
$$V_{bi} = V_n - V_p = \frac {q}{3\epsilon} \left( Sx_p^3 + Kx_n^3\right)$$
From here I am not sure how to get an expression for depletion width $W = x_p + x_n$